# How to use SMOTE in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

There is a module named [SMOTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/9f3fe1c4-520e-49ac-a152-2e104169912a)(Synthetic Minority Oversampling Technique ) which increase the number of samples of under sampled data, I guess we should choose a feature(feature to be predicted) which is under represented. How to choose it? There seems to be no option on choosing the coloumn.

Comment: What, exactly, are you talking about? What is smote? What's it a module for? You haven't tagged your question with anything but [tag:azure]. What will be the odds that someone seeing your question will know what this means and will be able to answer you? You really need to edit your question, both with meaningful tags and meaningful content.

Comment: In the link provided in the question there is a phrase "choose the column" I cannot find it in Azure. Its 2AM where I am working. So could not help write a bad question.

Comment: ok, so now you added [tag:machine-learning] and a link to smote, which helps immensely.

Comment: Is there any specific point in my question you did not understand?

Comment: As I stated in my prior comment, you clarified it - you were working in machine learning, with your edit. Prior to editing your question, it was just an unknown term 'smote' with something about a column. Zero reference beyond that. You had merely an Azure tag. Anyone not familiar with ML would simply not know what this question was about.

Comment: adding the Azure-ml tag triggered my mailing list, will reach out to internal and try and get an answer back soon.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are referring to the target variable (label column). You can set that using a Metadata Editor module. Choose your label column using the column selector and set the Fields property to Labels.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the SMOTE definition - SMOTE is an approach for the construction of classifiers from imbalanced datasets, which is when classification categories are not approximately equally represented. The classification category is the feature that the classifier is trying to learn. There is not an option of choosing the column in the SMOTE module because it should be the label column

Here is the details on how to use SMOTE in Azure Machine Learning - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn913076.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

You can do it thru the column selector. In the sample below, the blood donation data (a sample dataset in Azure ML) has 25% of people who donated (class 1).

[image]